# How to choose the features for a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, feature-selection, feature-extraction

I know that there is no a clear answer for this question, but let's suppose that I have a huge neural network, with a lot of data and I want to add a new feature in input. The "best" way would be to test the network with the new feature and see the results, but is there a method to test if the feature IS UNLIKELY helpful? Like [correlation measures](http://www3.nd.edu/%7Emclark19/learn/CorrelationComparison.pdf) etc?

Comment: A non-random correlation might be an indicator that the feature *is* useful. But I'm not so sure about pre-training tests that could rule ideas out. The paper you link makes it clear that non-linear correlations are not well detected by the available tests, but a neural net has a chance of finding and using them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A very strong correlation between the new feature and an existing feature is a fairly good sign that the new feature provides little new information.  A low correlation between the new feature and existing features is likely preferable.

A strong linear correlation between the new feature and the predicted variable is an good sign that a new feature will be valuable, but the absence of a high correlation is not necessary a sign of a poor feature, because neural networks are not restricted to linear combinations of variables.

If the new feature was manually constructed from a combination of existing features, consider leaving it out.  The beauty of neural networks is that little feature engineering and preprocessing is required -- features are instead learned by intermediate layers.  Whenever possible, prefer learning features to engineering them.

Comment: I always thought to compare the value to predict with the features, you are talking about correlation between features. Is your answer applicable also to my case? in theory I should add only new features that are correlated to the value to predict, right?

Comment: That's also a valuable metric -- just updated my answer  to address that as well.

Comment: In short, strong correlations with the value to predict is a great sign, but weak correlation with the value to predict is not necessarily a bad sign.

Comment: Thanks. I'm writing a report and I wanted to show the linear/non-linear correlations in order to justify the features (even before the results). Does it make any sense?
From your answer I could make a matrix of correlations but maybe it's nosense

Comment: A matrix of correlations would make more sense if you were performing linear regression, but it could also be a useful metric for neural nets.  Give it a go and see what you get!

Comment: I would use non-linear correlations, but ok thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using scikit-learn, there is a good function available called `model.feature_importances_`.

Give it a try with your model/new feature and see if it helps. Also look [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-in-python-with-scikit-learn/) and [here](http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-iii-random-forests/) for examples.